# How to detect unique visitors in phonegap app using google analytical for Android and IOS

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics

I am using GoogleAnalytics SDK for Android and IOS. i have created a PhoneGap application. Now i would like to get Unique  visitors or users of my application.
I am using following code for GoogleAnalytics

```
GoogleAnalytics ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(cordova.getActivity());
Tracker tracker = ga.getDefaultTracker(); 

tracker = ga.getTracker("UA-00000000-0");
GAServiceManager.getInstance().setDispatchPeriod(10);
ga.setDefaultTracker(tracker);
```

Is there any way to get unique users based on his UserID?

Answer (score 0):

Though this isn't an answer on how to accomplish what you want *in Google Analytics*, here is how you can accomplish what you want with a different tool. Quantcast Measure for Apps has a PhoneGap plugin that will provide you with unique users and user retention based on a user ID that your provide.

Links:

- [Read More about Quantcast Measure for Apps](https://info.quantcast.com/MeasureApps_mk.html)
- [Get the Quantcast PhoneGap plugin on Github](https://github.com/quantcast/phonegap-measurement)
- [Details on how to track users based on your user ID](https://github.com/quantcast/phonegap-measurement#combined-webapp-audiences)

You'll be able to produce cohort-based total uniques and user retention analysis. If you have a website, you'll be able to do the same cross-platform.

*Disclaimer - I work at Quantcast*